# Get Memory Ram and CPU Usage from process

Tags: delphi

How i can get memory ram and cpu usage used of my process? not from entire CPU.

all codes who i search on internet always retrieve from entire CPU, but i need retrieve these informations from my own process.

i'm using delphi 10.1

these code above who i did with others examples show very near the real memory usage:

```
var
  ProcHand        : THandle;
  i               : integer;
  WorkingSet      : array[0..$3FFF - 1] of DWORD;
  Shared, Privates, total : Integer;
begin
  ProcHand := OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, GetCurrentProcessId);

  Shared    := 0;
  Privates  := 0;
  total     := 0;

  if QueryWorkingSet(ProcHand, @WorkingSet, SizeOf(WorkingSet)) then
  begin
    for I := 1 to WorkingSet[0] do
    begin
      if ((WorkingSet[I] and $00000FFF) and $100 <> 0) then Inc(Shared) else Inc(Privates);

      Application.ProcessMessages;
    end;
  end;

  total     := WorkingSet[0] * 4;
  Shared    := Shared * 4;

  Result := Format('%.2f e %f > Memory %.2f', [total / 1024, shared / 1024, ((total / 1024) - (shared / 1024))]);

  CloseHandle(ProcHand);
```

the code are based on https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87529/Calculate-Memory-Working-Set-Private-Programmatica

Comment: Program memory usage, [How to get the Memory Used by a Delphi Program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/437683/576719). Program cpu usage, [How to retrieve cpu usage per process](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1708492/576719)

Comment: already tested these codes and don't show the memory used like task manager.

Comment: Then you need to read [Can memory be cleaned up?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031886/576719)

Comment: yes, what i'm trying do are show working set (total - shared) who is the consumn of process.

Comment: i updated question with an example